# ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable is not defined when searching for a node by attribute

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, e4x

I've done this lot of times, but now I'm missing something....
I'm searching for a node by looking for a value in an attribute.

If I try to trace:

```
 xmlQuestStructure.page[activePageIndex].label.@priority
```

The trace it's ok, and I can read High, Medium, Low (the values I'm expecting).

But if I try to trace this (where calculatedPriority is a String with value High, Medium or Low)

```
 xmlQuestStructure.page[activePageIndex].label.(@priority == calculatedPriority)
```

I get ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable priority is not defined

What am I doing wrong?
Thx for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, your problem is that one of your label nodes **DOESN'T** have a priority attribute defined.  When you use **@** in e4x, it will throw an error if it comes to a XML node that doesn't have the attribute specified.

If there is a possibility that your XMLnode could have the attribute omitted, then instead of using '@', use `attribute()`.

So in your case, you could do this:

```
xmlQuestStructure.page[activePageIndex].label.(attribute("priority") == calculatedPriority);
```

using `attribute()` is more passive, and will ignore the node if it doesn't have the specified attribute, instead of throwing an error.

Comment: If this isn't your problem, post your XML file (or at least part of it)

Comment: Man, thx. I just figured out what the problem was, and I was trying to use the attribute method, but I didn't know I could do the query as you say! Awesome